# JMeter Save Result when Test already finished

Tags: jmeter

I know that I need configure Jmeter to save result before a test will be started.
Everyone is any way exist to save results for a test already finished. It means that I get all responses etc? I want to save "View Result in Table", "Response Time Graph".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should be running your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

If you have this `result.jtl` file you can get the parsed results in several ways, i.e.:

1. Open JMeter GUI, add a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice and load the `result.jtl` file using "Browse" button

   [image: JMeter Open Results file with a listener]
2. You can generate a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of the .jtl results file like:

   ```
   jmeter -g result.jtl -o /path/to/folder/where/you/want/the/dashboard/to/be/generated
   ```
3. You can use [JMeter Plugins Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which can generate various tables and charts out of the .jtl results file. This is not a part of vanilla JMeter installation and you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

---

For GUI mode if you executed the test without Listeners - there is no way to see the results.

Comment: I have been using only Jmeter GUI. There the second way hasn't worked. The file isn't created. BTW Are y a Russian сложный русский текст?